# Why does this code display an exception?

Tags: java, for-loop, exception, java.util.scanner

I first wanna get 2 inputs as first and second parameters. Then to display all odd numbers between this parameters.
This is the output that I get even if I imported the java util:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:16)
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("first");
        int a = ask.nextInt();
        System.out.print("second");
        int b = ask.nextInt();

        int sum = 0;
        for (int n = a; n <= b; n++) {
            if (n % 2 == 1) {
                sum = sum + n;
                System.out.print(n + " ");

            }
        }
        System.out.print("*" + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work when I run it. What input are you giving?

Comment: I'm using an online IDE: https://www.compilejava.net/

Comment: It doesn't get to the point to make me enter anything.. It gives exception before that..

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: When you invoke ask.nextInt() make sure that you pass valid integer during runtime.. As Scanner.nextInt() search only for integer input and other types throw NoSucheElementexception

Comment: @MarieMirbekian use offline compiler

Comment: works online if your online compiler supports supplying input: https://ideone.com/0YIGUI

Comment: aaaa interesting ! thank you !